# How to solve RPostgreSQL error while reading the table from the database?

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, openstreetmap

Using osm2pgsql I have loaded a data from .osm.pbf file to the postgreSQL database. Now I want to access the "planet_osm_polygons" table from the postgres database. My R code is as below:

```
con <- dbConnect("PostgreSQL", dbname = "osmdb",
               host = "localhost", port = 5432,
               user = "postgres", password = "root")

if(dbExistsTable(con, "planet_osm_polygon")){
df <- dbReadTable(con, "planet_osm_polygon")
head(df)
}else{
    print("Table not found in the database!")
}
```

I have checked dbExistsTable() and it returns me TRUE for the indicated table name. Which means the table exists but for dbReadTable() it throws me this:

```
Warning message:
In postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :
  RS-DBI driver warning: (unrecognized PostgreSQL field type geometry (id:80871) in column 68)
```

I have searched allot on many blogs but couldn't any solution of this problem. Kindly help me in solving this simple issue. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: In general, data types don't always line up between a DB and R, so when moving data back and forth things need to be converted to suitable data types. It looks like you have a column in the table that doesn't map cleanly to an R data type. If RPostresSQL doesn't support that conversion natively (I honestly don't know) then you might have to convert that column to another data type within the DB.

Comment: @joran, sorry for replying here late. Yes you are right, it was due to the data type of the table. Thanks :)